# "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred", Azure Website,

Tags: azure, web

I have deployed the azure website to East US location, Reserved instance. I have CustomErrors=On. After few minutes of work (with quite good performance) app is hanging, slowing down. (I don't see any errors in elmah.) After that starts to return 500 error. My custom error page is not displayed (I see only "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred." in plain text) so I can't even customize it. Then the app is restarted. We cannot go into production like that. I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 19):

I had this same issue with VS2013 today.

My WCF-Services website worked fine locally, but it refused to work when it was published to Azure.

In VS2013 Update 2, I imported the Azure Publish Profile file, published to Azure, but always got this message:

```
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred
```

Even my basic **Default.htm** file, which displayed a simple "*This is default.htm*" message, refused to display, and, again, I'd just get that same message.

**Solution**

Thankfully, I had a second WCF-Service which *was* publishing correctly to Azure, so I compared it's web.config file to the "faulty" project's web.config file.

I found that I needed to manually strip the "**system.web**" section down to just this:

```
<system.web>
   <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
   <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" requestPathInvalidCharacters="" />
</system.web>
```

(which removed a load of assemblies, pages\controls, httpHandlers and httpModules stuff) 
and also completely get rid of the "**system.webServer**" section.

Once I'd done this, I *could* publish to Azure, and it'd all work fine.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was unable to just wipe the <system.web> elements out for production, but I did discover a logging component (Elmah) that probably needed updating after an MVC5 upgrade. So picking through the <system.web> items nailed it on the head for me.

Comment: when I remove system.webserver I get You do not have permission to view this directory or page. this page message, when I add system.webserver I get "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred."  any help please

Comment: I had the same issue but for specific URL alone in my web app that is deployed in azure. Any suggestion is helpful.

Comment: Above issue due to specific URL and application root directory having similar names. Issue resolved on deleting the directory.

Answer (score 7):

The best advice I can give to troubleshoot your problem is to check the website diagnostics logs. You can download log locally as described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2012/06/19/windows-azure-website-uploading-downloading-files-over-ftp-and-collecting-diagnostics-logs.aspx).

If you use new Windows Azure Powershell 0.6.12 you can use Powershell commands to download the logs directly using the following commands:

```
azure site log tail [options] [name] //{Retrieves the value for the selected key}
  --filter - Filter to match against for displaying log output.
  --log - Write output in a log format.
```

Above command streams live diagnostic logs from your website to the console --path [path] - Path under the LogFiles folder to pull logs from.

More info on PS: https://github.com/windowsazure/azure-sdk-tools-xplat

Also you can contact Azure Websites team through [forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/windowsazurewebsitespreview/threads) and ask for assistance.

Comment: I have some memory issues. (Traced this with mini profiler) Lots of objects is removed from asp.net cache. Maybe GC is hanging application. No idea. We decided move to provisioned server because site was stopped without any warning Friday/Saturday night because we have used all free transfer. We decided that provisioned server will be safer for now. We will use cloud for less critical tasks.

Answer (score 4):

I also just had this problem. In my case, the web.config was simply invalid due to a manual edit:
I changed the database password and copy & pasted the new one into the web.config.

The password had an ampersand (&) in it and I forgot to encode it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and finally solved it by turning the pool of my application to Classic instead of Integrated.
I didn't find this option on the azure portal and had to open the "old azure management platform".

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, i just changed Target Framework from 3.5 to 4.5 in project properties.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue - realized that i had deleted the wwwroot folder with my ftp upload.
recreated the folder and added site - works.

Answer (score 0):

You probably exceeded the storage limit.

I had the same issue with my web app (WordPress) and could fix it by accessing my website via FTP and deleting unnecessary backups in the `wp-content/ai1wm-backups` folder.

You can find your FTP credentials in `Deployment center`>>`FTP credentials`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too.
What I've done was to change the .NET version in stack settings under the "Settings" tab of my app service on Azure.
This solved my issue.
Hope it will help some of you.

Answer (score -1):

just remove mime type from web config and it resolved

Answer (score -3):

This is a custom error made from the `web.config` file setting below

```
<system.web>
   <customErrors mode="Off" />
</system.web>
```

Which is a custom error , if you're working on a website and you get this error after configuring a custom domain. You should start a new instance of the site on azure then make sure you have all the things setup event the domain name before you publish the website from visual studio or whatever you use to deploy your web apps.