# Wordpress on Azure, 504, media not uploading, can't remove a plugin

Tags: wordpress, azure, media, gateway

I'm at the end of the line,

I get inconsistant 504 Gateway Time-out, plugins disable or not.

I try and upload media and see the progress bar go up but when it reached the 100% I get that the image is to big (which it's not). Sometimes I will get 504's here with an eventual 502 and then the  web app seems to restart

I'm trying to clear some plugins since that might be the issue but when I try and delete a couple
of plugins, it doesn't. The text says deleting but it never goes.

I checked the permissions and they seem fine (drwxr-xr-x 1 Unknown+User Unknown+Group).
I've tried all 7 steps from WPBeginngers.  https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-504-gateway-timeout-error-in-wordpress/  [clear cache and reload, VPN, Firewall, Proxy, DNS, Database, plugins-n-theme]
Plenty of ram, space, memory alocation (to my best ability and other staff here).
I've disabled all of the plugins and theme with no differences.
The debug.log file has nothing.
No cache plugins on.

Why can I find the issue?! What else can I try?

PS, I AM THE HOST, so please no 'contact your host'

Comment: What are you hosting it on? Could it be your VM / App Service / Database might be under-provisioned? Try to see what'll happen if you scale them up.

Comment: Azure P1V2, PHP 7.4, MySQL 5.7, Wordpress 5.8.1 multisite/network. From what we're gaging for (300 sites) we're far from reaching the capacity. CPU and Mem charts are low with scaling running on 2 instances with a max of 8 (which it hasn't move to 3 instances)

Comment: The owner should be `www-data` or equivalent Apache/Nginx user. Is this running on Apache & Ubunutu (or other Linux server)?

Comment: It's actually running windows

Comment: I tried scaling up the servers with no changes. I even scaled down the instances to 1 and the site is still responding ok, minus the 504 while uploading

Answer (score 1):

After multiple days working with Microsoft Support, we tested theories flip on and off almost every switch possible.
We went back and started a process of elemination.
After reviewing the Application Gateway settings we moved to the App Service. We tried simple readme.html files with success in KUDU. We tried a 'hello world' php file and we got the gateway error or [The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15703316/the-page-cannot-be-displayed-because-an-internal-server-error-has-occurred-az).
Typical steps for WordPress reestablishment didn't prove fruitful either. Plugins, memeory allocation in .user.ini and such.
We then looked at changing the PHP version to see if we would get different errors.
PS, log files were not working.
At this time, Azure only offered PHP 7.4 so we couldn't switch it back and forth for trials. It's at this point we descided to rebuild the App Service and see if we can get a simple site up. This was a succeess.

Our final assessment was that the PHP engine had failed or had issues. The site was eventually copied over and as the files came up the sites started to show life.

If you run in this issue, you may have the option to lower or increase the PHP version. We could have tried to rebuild the PHP on the server but creating the new App Service was a better choice. It allowed us to also eleminate that the grouping of the App Service was faulty.

It has been days now and the sites are stable, there are no reports of gateways or down pages.